# Getter Setter with Java Custom type List Collections

Tags: java, json, list, encapsulation

Since I am newbie to java and I have below query, on List Collection.

Getter Setter Class:

```
public Person {
 private String name;
 private int age;

 public Person(String name, int age) {
   this.name = name;
   this.age = age
 }

 public String getName() {
    return name;
 }

 public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
 }
 etc...
}
```

I have the requirement, India team has 3 persons, Aus team has 3 persons.

> In my controller: Need persons/ind and persons/aus

Aus & India persons are in separate data source,

I tried in controller:

```
/persons/ind
public List<Person> listss {
  List<Person> lis = /* how to call here?? */;
  //how to add data to lis? simple static data?
  return lis;
}
```

So I want return to json format india with 3 persons, Aus with 3 persons.

Comment: To serialise your data you can use jackson: https://www.baeldung.com/jackson

Comment: But there is no country property in Person class, how can you filter them, show us what you tried so far.

Comment: I am struck with pushing list of data(atleast 3 persons, for one country).[+India, Aus has separate tables.]
In Controller I tried like 
public List<Person> lists() {
   List<Person> lis = ???
   //how to add data?
   return lis
}

Comment: Are you asking how to create a list of `Person` objects and how to add objects to it?

Answer (score 0):

This is one way you can create a list of `Person` objects with static data:

```
public List<Person> createPersonList() {
    List<Person> list = new ArrayList<>(); 
    list.add(new Person("Alice", 30));
    list.add(new Person("Bernard", 40));
    list.add(new Person("Charles", 50));
    return list;
}
```